# How to retain original cell value in lambda `else` in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas.
I am trying to retain original cell value per row, If the condition is NOT met.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = '\t')
df['New_Value'] = df['Old_Value'].apply(lambda x : 'OK' if x == 'Low' else x[df.Old_Value])
```

[ExpectedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRCYf.png)

Comment: wouldn't `else x` be what you are looking for?

Comment: kpie is correct. to hopefully clear it up a bit: the lambda operates over that particular series cell by cell, and that's all it knows about within its scope. in other words, you can't reference the column/series as a part of the DataFrame from within that lambda's scope.

Comment: Thanks. Else 'x' works. For my knowledge : what would be  the correct syntax for : "x[df.Old_Value]" ? If I want x to read another column in dataframe ?

Comment: meaning something like : df['New_Value'] = df['Old_Value'].apply(lambda x : x['another_column'].value  if x == 'Low' else x)

Comment: You couldn't do that by applying the lambda to one column but you could do it by applying a lambda to the row.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Old_Value': ['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'Mid']})
df['New_Value'] = df['Old_Value'].where(df['Old_Value'] != 'Low', other='OK')
print(df)

# Output
  Old_Value New_Value
0       Low        OK
1      High      High
2       Low        OK
3       Mid       Mid
```

**Note**: the condition is inverted: keep the original value if the condition is true else use `other`

`numpy` have the same function [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['New_Value'] = np.where(df['Old_Value'] == 'Low', 'OK', df['Old_Value'])
```